# How to 'rename' IPs in a subnet while they go through WireGuard?

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, wireguard

first question here, I hope I'm at the right spot.

I have successfully configured WireGuard on my Linux server and am able to connect my laptop to it. The laptop is able to access a subnet that's on the server side, let's say `192.168.129.1/24` for the sake of example. To be more precise, my server redirects all traffic, so I just specify the IPs that I need in `AllowedIPs`, e.g. `192.168.129.13/32`.

Here's my `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` for reference:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.2.1/24
PrivateKey = <snip>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <snip>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.2/32
```

My question is: how do I 'rename' the IPs like `192.168.129.13` to a different subnet, so that I can be more certain there will be no conflicts with whatever subnet I'm working in?

Bonus question: what would be a good subnet? Something that isn't used by ISPs for home networks?

Comment: 'rename' of IPs is usually called NAT (network address translation). The only shared subnet that won't cause conflicts with home networks (RFC 1918) is 100.64.0.0/10 (RFC 6598) but it can cause conflicts with your ISP network. Otherwise, you need to purchase an address space from a registry (LIR).

Comment: Every ISP uses a different subnet, so you need to check in your modem/router what they use.